# Case Sensitive Partial Match with Boost's Regex

Tags: c++, regex, boost

From the following code, I expect to get this output from the corresponding input:

```
Input: FOO     Output: Match
Input: FOOBAR  Output: Match
Input: BAR     Output: No Match
Input: fOOBar  Output: No Match
```

But why it gives "No Match" for input FOOBAR?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;


int main  ( int arg_count, char *arg_vec[] ) {
   if (arg_count !=2 ) {
       cerr << "expected one argument" << endl;
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   string InputString = arg_vec[1];
   string toMatch = "FOO";

   const regex e(toMatch);
   if (regex_match(InputString, e,match_partial)) {
       cout << "Match" << endl;
   } else {
       cout << "No Match" << endl;
   }


   return 0;
}
```

**Update:**

Finally it works with the following approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

bool testSearchBool(const boost::regex &ex, const string st) {
    cout << "Searching " << st << endl;
    string::const_iterator start, end;
    start = st.begin();
    end = st.end();
    boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> what;
    boost::match_flag_type flags = boost::match_default;
    return boost::regex_search(start, end, what, ex, flags);
}


int main  ( int arg_count, char *arg_vec[] ) {
    if (arg_count !=2 ) {
        cerr << "expected one argument" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    string InputString = arg_vec[1];
    string toMatch = "FOO*";

    static const regex e(toMatch);
    if ( testSearchBool(e,InputString) ) {
        cout << "MATCH" << endl;
    }
    else {
         cout << "NOMATCH" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression has to account for characters at the beginning and end of the sub-string "FOO".
I'm not sure but "FOO*" might do the trick

match_partial would only return true if the partial string was found at the end of the text input, not the beginning.

> A partial match is one that matched
>   one or more characters at the end of
>   the text input, but did not match all
>   of the regular expression (although it
>   may have done so had more input been
>   available)

So FOOBAR matched with "FOO" would return false.
As the other answer suggests, using regex.search would allow you to search for sub-strings more effectively.

Comment: @Gayan: I tried, string toMatch = "FOO*"; It still doesn't match.

Comment: It was just a hunch. I don't have the luxury of writing a test app using boost. Sorry

Comment: This isn't shell expansion.  "FOO*" would be an 'F', followed by an 'O', followed by zero or more 'O's.

Comment: Yep. I thought so. I don't remember much about regular expressions. FOO[a-z]*[A-Z]*?

Answer (score 1):

Use `regex_search` instead of `regex_match`.